ASRock Killer SLI won't boot with a Ryzen 3700X, no post
I’ve updated my BIOS to 5.40 in order to be able to be able to replace my 1800X with a 3700X, following the instructions on
https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/X370%20Killer%20SLI/index.asp#BIOS
Now my fans start spinning up att full blast as soon as I boot, keep spinning at pretty high rate, and spin up cyclically from medium intenstity to full blast, almost like they would in a boot loop. They never stop spinning unless the system sleeps, even with no processes running. Other than that, the system is running normally.
When I try to switch to the 3700X, the system doesn't boot or post. (I've reset the CMOS, booting with just RAM stick, to no avail).
When I switch back to the 1800X, the system boots just fine, except the fans spin in that weird way.
Also, the system is now seeing two of my RAM sticks as 8GB each, not 16GB. Previously, they were being properly addressed.
Any idea what’s going on?
System:
Windows 10
ASRock Killer SLI
Ryzen 7 1800X
64GB RAM
RTX Titan
Corsair CX750

What BIOS version did you update from?

5.10. I was attempting to follow your instructions and those of ASRock:


Update to P3.50


Update to P5.10


install AMD all in 1 with VGA driver ver:18.10.20_NHDA
or a later version before updating to this BIOS.

Update to P5.40

install AMD all in 1 with VGA driver ver:18.50.16.01_WHQL
or a later version before updating to this BIOS.

Replace 1800X with 3700X


You say you updated to 3.50 then 5.10 and then 5.40 ... so, what version did you START from, clearly was before 3.50 - the fan thing you probably just need to fix the fan curve/settings in BIOS. The RAM issue looks odd, I take it you have 4 x 16GB ram sticks? Try booting with a single stick at a time maybe to see if it's a particular stick that is misrecognised

I didn't take note of what BIOS I started with, it was 1.40 or something, as the ASRock page doesn't mention anything specific to consider when updating from older BIOSes.
I've tried booting with a single stick, shuffling them around, cleaned the slots and the sticks, made sure they're seated properly, etc.
It's consistently 2 of the 4 sticks that aren't recognized as 16GB any longer. I've only had these two for a few months, and they've worked perfectly until now:

